# How to create a link to directly edit a SharePoint list item

Tags: url, edit, sharepoint-online, power-automate, editmode

I have a SharePoint online 2016 site, with a List. Now i want to have a URL (build in MS Flow) that will point directly to a specific item in Edit mode.

Meaning to have this view (**both list behind and right "popup" screen**):
[image]

**And not like this (Copy link url)**
[image]

I am able to have it opened in full screen but not like the screenshot.
Can anyone tell me if this is even possible?

I have looked into these:

- http://mmkhome.blogspot.com/2010/12/sharepoint-edit-page-url-querystring.html
- http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2012/09/open-sharepoint-2010-display-edit-new.html
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c27e2cdd-bddb-473c-9782-0309e026204f/to-show-a-editform-in-dialog-box?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious
- https://www.spcnl.nl/redirect-link-to-item-url-from-out-microsoft-flow-to-editform-instead-of-displayform/

and tried literally everything suggested in all these links but no luck.
Things like:

```
Web URL/Lists/List Name/AllItems.aspx?displaymode=design 
Web URL/Lists/List Name/EditForm.aspx?ID={List item ID}    
/DispForm.aspx?ID=...
/EditForm.aspx?ID=...
?ID=123&pagemode=edit   
?ID=123&mode=edit 
PageType=4
```

**Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devtools shows that after clicking on "Edit" button above list name (the way you open this extended edit menu from first screenshoot), a REST API call is fired:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test_site/
_api/web/GetList(%27%2Fsites%2Ftest%5Fsite%2FLists%2Ftest%5Flist%27)
/RenderExtendedListFormData(itemId=4,formId='editform',mode='2',options=15,cutoffVersion=0)
```

And that's it - `RenderExtendedListFormData` method fetch data and later, I guess, JavaScript does the rest of magic and slides out the edit menu.

To sum up: I am afriad it will be not possible using only pure URL.

Comment: So you think that there is Javascript that is executed after the response that is taking care of the rendering of the Edit menu popup/modal screen ? And if so, wouldn't it be possible to send that request in a HttpRequest in MS Flow to have the same result?

Comment: I am not a front-end developer but AFAIK it is a standard architecture.

Comment: Alright thank you very much. I will take a shot at HTTPRequest in MS Flow but if anyone else has suggestions or info please feel free to do so!